# Detecting if Mac has a backlit keyboard

Tags: swift, macos, hardware, iokit

It’s quite easy to detect if Mac has an illuminated keyboard with `ioreg` at the command line:

```
ioreg -c IOResources -d 3 | grep '"KeyboardBacklight" =' | sed 's/^.*= //g'
```

But how can I programmatically get this `IOKit` boolean property using the latest Swift? I’m looking for some sample code.

Comment: You could always just run this shell command with NSTask.

Comment: @idmean That’s exactly what I’m doing now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the following with some trial and error:

- Get the "IOResources" node from the IO registry.
- Get the "KeyboardBacklight" property from that node.
- (Conditionally) convert the property value to a boolean.

I have tested this on an MacBook Air (with keyboard backlight) and on an iMac (without keyboard backlight), and it produced the correct result in both cases.

```
import Foundation
import IOKit

func keyboardHasBacklight() -> Bool {
    let port: mach_port_t
    if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
        port = kIOMainPortDefault // New name as of macOS 12
    } else {
        port = kIOMasterPortDefault // Old name up to macOS 11
    }
    let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(port, IOServiceMatching(kIOResourcesClass))
    guard service != IO_OBJECT_NULL else {
        // Could not read IO registry node. You have to decide whether
        // to treat this as a fatal error or not.
        return false
    }
    guard let cfProp = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, "KeyboardBacklight" as CFString,
                                                       kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)?.takeRetainedValue(),
          let hasBacklight = cfProp as? Bool
    else {
        // "KeyboardBacklight" property not present, or not a boolean.
        // This happens on Macs without keyboard backlight.
        return false
    }
    // Successfully read boolean "KeyboardBacklight" property:
    return hasBacklight
}
```

Comment: I did a little bit of research after you posted and I was wondering why didn’t you use `IOServiceMatching` and `IOServiceGetMatchingServices`? Since I require macOS 12 or later, I will be using the newest `kIOMainPortDefault` instead of older `kIOMasterPortDefault`. Thanks!

Comment: @Tzar: You are right, `IOServiceGetMatchingService(..., IOServiceMatching("IOResources"))` would also work. `IORegistryEntryFromPath(...)` was the first version I managed to get running. I doubt that there is a functional difference, so pick your choice :) – I am still on macOS 11.6, therefore I did not notice the renamed property. You can of course use kIOMainPortDefault instead.

Comment: @Tzar: Rewritten to use kIOMainPortDefault on macOS 12, and IOServiceMatching with a predefined constant instead of a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [Martin’s excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362387/7840155), here are the notes I got from Apple’s Developer Technical Support:

> Calling I/O Kit from Swift is somewhat challenging. You have
> two strategies here:
>
> - You can wrap the I/O Kit API in a Swift-friendly wrapper and then use    that to accomplish your task.
> - You can just go straight to your task, resulting in lots of ugly    low-level Swift.

---

> Pulling random properties out of the I/O Registry is *not* the best path
> to long-term binary compatibility. Our general policy here is that we
> only support properties that have symbolic constants defined in the
> headers (most notably `IOKitKeys.h`, but there are a bunch of others).
> `KeyboardBacklight` has no symbolic constant and thus isn’t supported.

---

> Make sure you code defensively. This property might go away, change
> meaning, change its type, and so on. Your code must behave reasonable
> in all such scenarios.

---

> Please make sure you file an [enhancement request](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) for a proper API to
> get this info, making sure to include a high-level description of your
> overall goal.

Comment: The updated code should meet that requirements (use predefined constants if available, code defensively) :)